# Unable to serve CSS

Tags: go, web-applications, static-files

I am having trouble getting the app to serve my CSS file. The Index page is loading, but the CSS itself is missing

Here is what my HTML sort of looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
```

My Http Handler:

```
h := &Handler{
    Mux: chi.NewMux(),
    store: *store,
}

// Serve static files
h.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("web"))))
h.Get("/", h.IndexPage())
```

And my directory structure:

```
├── main.go
└── web
    ├── handler.go
    ├── static
    │   └── style.css
    └── templates
        └── index.html
```

The terminal logs are:

```
"GET http://localhost:3000/ HTTP/1.1" - 200 
"GET http://localhost:3000/static/style.css HTTP/1.1" - 404
```

Comment: Don't strip the /static/ prefix or change the root directory to web/static.

Comment: @Peter, I tried to change root directory, but nothing changed